# What is the probability for m players to get opposite neighboring coins for n players in a circular table tossing a coin?

Tags: probability

Consider a setup where $n$ players sit on a circular table with a fair coin with each one of them. What is the probability that exactly $m$ players ($m<n$) have the neighbouring coins opposite?

For example, if there are 4 players, and we want exactly one of them to get a situation such that it's neighbouring coins are opposite (like heads and tails).

Comment: Are the "neighboring coins" of player $i$ the coins of players $i-1$ and $i+1$? Each of which has been flipped? If so, the probability for $m$ odd is very simple to compute ...

Comment: @DavidK Yes, everyone has flipped their coin at once. And can you post your answer then?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, 
let's just consider what values of $m$ are possible to reach.
Suppose the players have all flipped coins and $m$ players are now
between two coins with opposite outcomes.
Now one by one, turn over each coin that shows heads until all coins show tails.

Each time we turn over a coin, the player to the left either joins or leaves
the set of "players between coins with opposite outcomes",
and the same for the player on the right.
Nobody else joins or leaves that set.
So if we have $k$ players between opposite coins at any time during
this procedure, after turning one coin over we have either $k$, $k+2$,
or $k-2$ players between opposite coins.
That is, turning a coin over does not change the parity of the
number of players between opposite coins.

But after turning all the coins to tails, we have no players between
opposite coins. Since $0$ is even, $m$ must also have been even.
So if $X$ is the number of players between opposite coins,
$P(X=m) = 0$ whenever $m$ is odd;
we have non-trivial probabilities only for the cases where $m$ is even.

For the rest of this answer, assume that $m$ is even.

Number the players $0$ through $n-1$.
Let $X_i = 1$ if player $i$ is between opposite coins,
$X_i = 0$ otherwise for $i = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1.$
That is,
$$ X = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X_i.$$
Let $Y_i = 1$ if the coin of player $i$ shows heads, 
$Y_i = 0$ otherwise.
Then $X_i \equiv Y_{i-1} + Y_{i+1} \pmod2,$
where we define $Y_{-1} = Y_{n-1}$ and $Y_n = Y_0$
due to the fact that the players are sitting in a circle.
Note that $P(X_i = 1) = \frac12$ for every $i$.

Consider the case where $n$ is odd.
Put the $Y_i$ in the sequence
$$Y_1, Y_3, Y_5,\ldots,Y_{n-2}, Y_0, Y_2,\ldots,Y_{n-3}, Y_{n-1}.$$
Any two consecutive variables in this sequence determine
one of the $X_i$ in this sequence:
$$X_2, X_4, \ldots, X_{n-1}, X_1, X_3, \ldots, X_{n-2}.$$
For any particular sequence of $n-1$ values of these $X_i$,
there are two sequences of values of the $Y_i$ for which
that sequence of $X_i$ occurs; and since every possible
sequence of values of $Y_i$ is equally likely,
the probability for any particular sequence of values of $X_i$
to occur is $\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}.$
(There are $2^{n-1}$ such sequences,
and their probabilities sum to $1$.)
In other words, the $X_i$ in that sequence are 
$n-1$ i.i.d. random variables.

Note that $X_0$ is *not* in that set of i.i.d. variables.
In fact, once we know the values of $n-1$ of the $X_i$
(such as all the values for $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$),
the remaining $X_i$ is completely determined:
it is whatever value makes the sum of all the $X_i$ even.

Any particular sequence of values of $X_i$
therefore occurs with probability $\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}$;
that is, $n-1$ of the values each occurs with 
independent probability $\frac12,$
and the one remaining value is determined by the others.
There are $\binom nm$ different ways that exactly $m$ 
of the $X_i$ could be $1$, so
$$P(X=m) = \binom nm \left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}.$$
(Keep in mind that this formula is valid only for odd $n$.)

Now consider instead the case where $n$ is even.
This case is slightly more complicated, because the
odd-numbered coins determine the even-numbered $X_i$
and the even-numbered coins determine the odd-numbered $X_i$
independently.
We can still treat all of the $X_i$ as independent, however,
except for one of the even $X_i$ and one of the odd $X_i$
(which are completely determined by the other even $X_i$
and odd $X_i$, respectively).
Each particular sequence of all the $X_i$ occurs
therefore occurs with probability $\left(\frac12\right)^{n-2}.$
But there are not $\binom nm$ possible sequences;
a sequence of $X_i$ is possible only if there are an
even number of $1$s among the even-numbered $X_i$
(and therefore also an even number of $1$s 
among the odd-numbered $X_i$).
The number of ways this can happen is described by the function
$$f(n,m) =
 \frac12\left( \binom nm + (-1)^{m/2} \binom{n/2}{m/2} \right).$$
I don't have a particularly clever intuition for this result,
although I can prove it by a rather tedious double induction.
As a result,
$$P(X=m) =
 \left(\binom nm + (-1)^{m/2} \binom{n/2}{m/2}\right) 
 \left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}.$$
This is consistent with the relatively intuitive fact
that $P(X=0) = \left(\frac12\right)^{n-2}$.